# auto ? adding with Iframe when store into databse

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I am creating web API asp.net MVC in which I have one post request that accept string html tags like

```
<p><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/kGq7ZCth7QY' allowfullscreen='true' frameborder='0' width='100%' style=' height: 400px;'></iframe>​</p><p><br/></p><p>testing video post</p>
```

and this string html I am saving to database but after record saved in database it a "?" is added at the last of iframe tag and it looks like

```
<p><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/kGq7ZCth7QY' allowfullscreen='true' frameborder='0' width='100%' style=' height: 400px;'></iframe>?</p><p><br/></p><p>testing video post</p>
```

so can anyone have idea how the "?" is auto adding , I am using EF6 to save record.
thank you

Comment: can it be a UTF-8 or another encoding problem? Are your data and your pages using the same encoding?

Comment: actually data is come from front end texangular texbox which giving me this tags and I am saving it to database